# how to use dual foreign key in oracle 10g

Tags: oracle

I have created two tables

```
create table ref1(id varchar2(3) primary key);
create table ref2(id varchar2(3) primary key);
```

Now I want to create a third table with a single column as foreign key for both ref1.id and ref2.id

```
create table actual(p varchar2(3) );
```

How can i do it?

Comment: That sounds very strange. To me this implies a one-to-relationship between ref1 and ref2 so I don't see the benefit in this. What is it that you are ***really*** trying to achieve. Explain your *real* problem.

Comment: @a_horse: Suppose we have `Manager` and `Consultant` tables (both with 1:1 relationship with `Person`). A person can be manager or consultant or both or neither. Then we have a table `Decision` with a column `Authorized_by_Person_ID` which we want to ensure they (the decisions) are made by someone that is both a manager and a consultant.

Comment: @ypercube: thanks, nice example. I never thought about modelling something like that this way.

Comment: @ypercube But if a single column in `Person` references both of the other tables, then either it must be `NULL` (i.e. the person is neither manager nor consultant) or it must have a single value that matches rows in both of the other tables (i.e. the person is both manager and consultant).  If you wanted the ability to be one or the other but not both, wouldn't you need two separate columns in `Person`, one for `ManagerID` and one for `ConsultantID`?

Comment: @DaveCosta: No, I meant the FKs to be the other way around. From Manager to Person and from Consultant to Person. No Nulls and no FKs from Person to the other 2 tables.

Answer (score 14):

You could try this:

```
CREATE TABLE ref1
(
    id VARCHAR2(3) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE ref2
(
    id VARCHAR2(3) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE look
(
    p VARCHAR2(3),
    CONSTRAINT fk_p_ref1 FOREIGN KEY (p) REFERENCES ref1(id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_p_ref2 FOREIGN KEY (p) REFERENCES ref2(id)
);
```

Tested on a 10G R2 server with no complaint (yet).

---

**Edit**:

Simple test result:

```
SQL> insert into ref1 (id) values ('abc');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into ref2 (id) values ('def');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into look (p) values ('abc');
insert into look (p) values ('abc')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (LINEQZ.FK_P_REF2) violated - parent key not
found


SQL> insert into ref2 (id) values ('abc');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into look (p) values ('abc');

1 row created.
```

Comment: Impressive. One never stops learning.

Comment: It even works when the FKs are defined inline: `CREATE TABLE look( p VARCHAR(3) REFERENCES ref1(id) REFERENCES ref2(id) );`